# How to insert a Class on switch statement

Tags: php

In bootstrap 3 we have this `<li>` class set to **active** in order to display the current page highlighted on the navbar

```
<li class="active">
     <a href="linkaddress.html">Link</a>
</li>
```

the problem is when you are including the menu via include `includes/header.php;` on all your pages. i cant figure out how to put together a switch statement on the `$actual_link` and bring back some sort of call to insert the class active in the right place. this my so far attempt and im honestly stuck because i feel there is a better way. how can i can i put the `li` class to `active` with this switch

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$HTTPHost = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
switch($actual_link)
{
case "http://{$HTTPHost}/index.php" || 
    "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}/admin.php?edit_home":

//setToActive
    break;
case "http://{$HTTPHost}/warrants.php" || 
    "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}/admin.php?edit_warrants":
 //setToActive     
    break;
case "http://{$HTTPHost}/faq.php" || 
    "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}/admin.php?edit_faq":
 //setToActive 
    break;
case "http://{$HTTPHost}/aboutus.php" || 
    "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}/admin.php?edit_aboutus":
  //setToActive  
    break;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pages before including header set a variable to indicate the current page. For example in `index` page:

```
$active = 'index';
include('includes/header.php');
```

Now in your `header.php` while creating links use something like

```
<?php global $active ?>
<li <?php if( isset($active) && $active == 'index') echo 'class="active"'; ?>>
     <a href="index.php">Index</a>
</li>
```

Comment: looks like you forgot to put braces around echo

Comment: there is a mistake, is you set one to active, they all expect active so they all get highlighted, its not working but i guess i can do `index1, index2`

Comment: Glad that you liked the answer :). Braces are not mandatory for only a single statement inside if or loops. Refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726339/php-if-else-for-foreach-while-without-curly-braces

Comment: oh i see now -_- i feel stupid, index was for the index, and so on each one should have a name different lol sorry

Answer (score 0):

you can't specify multiple expression in a case statement like this

```
case "http://{$HTTPHost}/index.php" || 
    "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}/admin.php?edit_home":
```

the above expression evaluates to `true`.

use the following synatax

```
case "http://{$HTTPHost}/index.php":
case "http://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}/admin.php?edit_home":
     //statements 
     break;
```